# onLongClick LazyColumn JetpackCompose not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a code that will fetch Firestore data, all is working and also edit function is also working, now i wanted to add a function that if the user longpress it, it will give the user a decision to either delete or not delete the contact list. Here is the code

`  LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.onLongClick { index: Int ->
// Handle long press on a specific number
if (firefighters[index] != null) {
// Delete the firefighter from Firestore
val documentId = firefighters[index].documentId
val db = Firebase.firestore

```
                                db.collection("Emergency Contacts")
                                    .document("$finalMunicipalityForm")
                                    .collection("Firefighters")
                                    .document(documentId)
                                    .delete()
                                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                                        Log.d("DeleteNumber", "Number deleted successfully")
                                        // Update the firefighters list
                                        firefighters.removeAt(index)
                                        context.showToast("Number Deleted")
                                    }
                                    .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                                        Log.e("DeleteNumber", "Error deleting number", e)
                                    }
                            }
                        }) {
                            item {
```

`

This throws error

`LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.**onLongClick **{ index: Int ->`

i have imported this `import androidx.compose.foundation.Modifier` but still the Modifier Lit RED

I also tried to restart my pc

To be able to delete a contact number via long press

Answer (score 1):

You should use the modifier.combinedClick.

```
Modifier
                .combinedClickable(
                    onClick = { singleClick() },
                    onLongClick = { longClick() },
                    onLongClickLabel = "Long click"
                )
```

As stated on the docs here: [Tap and press - Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/touch-input/pointer-input/tap-and-press#long-press-show)